# How do I set XAML Elements from C# code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So i have wpf application and my xaml looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MyTest"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyTest.Layouts"
        xmlns:pl="clr-namespace:Planerator"
        Title="CardView" Topmost="False" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized" ShowInTaskbar="False">
    <Grid>
        <pl:Planerator x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="FrontProjection" Margin="240" >
            <my:FrontLayout />
        </pl:Planerator>

        <pl:Planerator x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="BackProjection" Margin="240" >
            <my:BackLayout />
        </pl:Planerator>
    </Grid>
    <Window.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush />
    </Window.Background>
</Window>
```

Is there a way to set the `<my:FrontLayout />` and `<my:FrontLayout />` for the Planerators inside my C# code?

EDIT:
Planerator: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2007/10/26/enter-the-planerator-dead-simple-3d-in-wpf-with-a-stupid-name.aspx

And the FrontLayot and BackLayout -s are just simple xaml layouts.

EDIT2: The reason why i need to set them from code is that i want o use conditional compilasion. because for example for DEBUG it should be `<my:DebugFrontLayer />` .

Comment: Please revise your title to something more descriptive of the question.

Comment: Can you post your class definitions for pl:Planerator, my:FrontLayout and my:BackLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Planerator class you'll see it has the [`ContentPropertyAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute.aspx) set:

```
[ContentProperty("Child")]
public class Planerator : FrameworkElement
{
}
```

This means that

```
  <pl:Planerator x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="FrontProjection" Margin="240" >
    <my:FrontLayout />
  </pl:Planerator>
```

Actually does this:

```
  <pl:Planerator x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="FrontProjection" Margin="240" >
    <pl:Planerator.Child>
      <my:FrontLayout />
    </pl:Planerator.Child>
  </pl:Planerator>
```

Which also means that from code-behind, for example in the constructor of MyTest, or anywhere else really, you could do the following to achieve the same:

```
    public MyTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        FrontProjection.Child = new FrontLayout();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give them names, e.g.

```
<my:FrontLayout Name="FrontLayout1" />
```

and then they should be accessible from C# as variables of that name.